# Is ずから a productive structure?

Tags: etymology

Recently, I was reminded of 手ずから again and connected it to 自ら{みずか} and おのずから this time. I was wondering if the structure ずから is used anywhere else? Some research seems to indicate that might be related to つ+柄.

Comment: That's interesting! Bookmarking for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I researched and found some words which have similar meaning with these samples.

- 口ずから (by one's own mouth)
- 足ずから (by one's own feet)
- 心ずから (by one's own heart/will)

As a different meaning, ず+から seems to lead a meaning of relationship.

- 隣ずから (with relationship of next to each other)
- いとこずから (with relationship of cousins)

In my experience, these words I shared are rare especially in modern Japanese.

As you mentioned, this pattern seems to be derived from "つ"(one of particle) + "柄"(essence) like "身つ柄" → みずから. The particle "つ" is almost the same as "の". Surprisingly, "つ" in まつげ(eyelash) was originally the same as this particle meaning ま(目 eye) + つ + げ(毛 hair) meaning "eyes' hair". "柄" is common in modern Japanese like "人柄"(personality) and "家柄"(culture/custom of family).

Comment: I’m really fascinated about how the 濁音 in some words shifts sometimes. It’s like a limited form of metathesis. 手伝う is another unexpected one compared to the naive 連濁 you might expect.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that 手伝う has a sound shifting!! Definitely unexpected in the case つ+から too. Not only the particle shifted つ→づ→ず but 柄 didn't change to がら.